# Can a CSS property be used on an XPath locator to ensure an element is visible?

Tags: python, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I've got a block of divs which you can click to reveal content in an accordion style.

I'm running through this block with selenium to open them all up and then ultimately capture a screenshot. However I'm unsure on how best to check that the accordion item has been displayed before moving on to the next one.

At the moment my test runs through but the final screenshot shows some items still closed. My code:

```
detailsAccordion = self.ff.find_elements_by_class_name('accordion')
index = 1
for option in detailsAccordion:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.ff, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordionContainer']/div["+
            str(index) +"]/h3[1]")).click()
        # Need a WebDriverWait here for style='display: block;' on the current div
    except:
        print "Can't access div #" + unicode(index)
    index = index + 1
```

If I add a line like;

```
WebDriverWait(self.ff, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element("//div[@class='accordionContainer']/div["+
                str(index) +"][@style='display: block;']"))
```

I get my exception prints, so is it possible to add a requirement on the display property of each div?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if any WebElement is visible or not by using the [is_displayed()](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_displayed) method provided by selenium API.

When you are looking for an element by xpath on a webpage, the selenium driver will automatically wait for the page to load before handing over control to your code. I did not see the need to use the WebDriverWait.

If the element is not present the code will give an element not found exception, but if it is present is_displayed() will return true or false based on whether it is visible or not.

Before taking the screenshot , check if the accordion item is visible, if visible then take a screenshot.

Maybe using an implicitWait will help you -

```
from selenium import webdriver

  ff = webdriver.Firefox()
  ff.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
```

Comment: I've tried the following but it doesn't wait for every item to open. Some fail, but with a time.sleep(1) they all work. `WebDriverWait(self.ff, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordionContainer']/div["+ str(index) +"]/div[@class='accordionContent']").is_displayed())`

Comment: An implicit wait would work, but thats effectively the same as a sleep which is what I'm trying to avoid. I'd rather webdriver could see that the CSS property of the div had been set to display: block to improve the speed of the script.

Comment: Implicit wait of 10 secs does not mean that the driver will wait for 10 seconds every time for the page to load. It means that if the driver does not find an element which you are looking for then it will wait for 10 secs. Therefore you do not lose time by using implicit wait.